# Display Arabic characters inside chosen drop down list

Tags: localization, character, arabic, jquery-chosen

I am not able to display Arabic characters inside chosen drop down list, any body can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more info or snippet of your code?
there is actually no reason for HTML to complain about Arabic or any other language, it will just show what you input.

check this fiddle for example:

```
`<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Display
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="action">السلام</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">عليكم</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">كيف</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">الحال؟</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4xfcvsw/100/

Comment: Than you Ali for your answer, Actually my problem occurs when I try to get Arabic text from resource file, If I insert Arabic characters direct in html just like your sample it works fine, but when it comes to resource files its not working.

Comment: still we need to see some code or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: you are assuming that we know what language you are using.
is it C# ASP.net
php
python
Xamarin 
...?

Comment: its ASP.net web form

Comment: are you using resource files with culture ?

Comment: there are global and local resources files
you also need to follow the standard and set the culture correctly

Comment: yes I using resourcces files with culture, I am using local resources and its implemented correctly and works fine for English resource. I will share with you a sample from my code